# Does tf.concat and tf.reshape truncate gradient flow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using an LSTM layer to generate a hidden state representation of some inputs. Then, I will reshape and concatenate this hidden state representation with other inputs to feed into a second LSTM layer.

Since my goal is to use end-to-end training on this model, I would like to know if backpropagation (through the AdaDelta optimizer) can flow throughout the entire computational graph including the first LSTM layer.

This is the general structure of the code:

```py
# Passing the initial inputs (time_block_inputs) into the first LSTM layer
hidden_state = tf.keras.layers.RNN(timewise_lstm_stack, return_sequences=True)(time_block_inputs)

# Reshaping the hidden state representation
hidden_state = tf.reshape(hidden_state, ...)
# Then concatenating it with more inputs (additional_inputs)
note_block_inputs = tf.concat([hidden_state, additional_inputs], 2)

# Getting the final outputs of the model
outputs = tf.keras.layers.RNN(notewise_lstm_stack, return_sequences=True)(note_block_inputs)

# Loss function defined using tf.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
loss = model.BiaxialLoss(outputs, y)
optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

If I evaluate train_op within a session, will the weights for the initial LSTM layer (timewise_lstm_stack) update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tf.concat and tf.reshape do not affect the gradients as these operations do not impact the differentiability from start to end. So you can train end-to-end.

If you want to check this, just look at the weights of the first LSTM. They will change after the updates.